# how to convert ckeditor html output to normal string and limit string

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, ckeditor

i am using laravel 5.5 trying to limit ckeditor string but its output me like this

My Database

```
<p> something something something something something </p>
```

i am trying like this

```
{!! substr($content,0, 20) !!}
```

Output

```
<p> something ...
```

and not closing paragraph that's why my page crash and not working fine

how can i convert ckeditor string to normal string and limit this

thanks

Comment: I thinks just save content in DB and code like this `<p>{!! substr($content,0, 20) !!}</p>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `strip_tags()`

```
{!! strip_tags(substr($content,0, 20)) !!}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
substr_replace($fetch_testimonials['fld_testinomial_description'], "...", 200);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.